# Function to calculate number of words, spaces, sentences, and average words per sentence

Tags: javascript, html

I'm tired and just trying to create a text area with a button that calls a function to read the text entered into the text area and calculates the number of words, spaces, sentences, and average words per sentence. I had an idea about how to go about it but at the moment I can only think of a way to count the characters. My other problem right now is an error that I'm getting, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null." I've been coding a bunch of stuff all day and my eyes are worn out. I need a fresh pair of eyes to look at it. If someone could help me out with the error (I'm just trying to get a response first) and maybe also give me some pointers on how to go about this, that would be great. However, it requires not using the .split() function.

HTML:

```
<p>Enter a string to calculate words, spaces, sentences, and average words per sentence.</p>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
</textarea>
 <center><div id = "output"></div></center>
    </div>
    <button id = "getResponse">Calculate</button>
```

JS:

```
var output = document.querySelector("#output");
getResponse = document.querySelector("#getResponse");
getResponse.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);

function clickHandler ()
{
output.innerHTML = "Hi"; 
}
```

I expect it to return "Hi" in the output div.

Reminder that I'm not asking for people to do the code for me! I'm asking for pointers, as said in my first explanation.

Comment: Works fine as-is.

Comment: so, you want output to say "Hi" when you click the button? Done

Comment: Why does it "require not using the .split() function". Is this for a class?

Comment: `it requires not using the .split() function` why have you put such a restriction on yourself?

Comment: `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null.` - where is your extensive code in relation to the markup? If it's executed before the markup has loaded, then querySelector won't find them

Comment: you could just use the `string.match()` method with the `g` modifier and count up the size of the arrays.

Comment: ^ Also if we can assume properly formatted input, the number of words should just be the number of spaces plus one so you can eliminate one calculation. If input can have any format, best to calculate them separately.

Comment: @ColinCline No, I asked for tips/pointers on how to go about it, not to have the entire code done for me.

Comment: Yes, this is for a class. Since I'm getting so many comments badgering me on how I'm trying to get people to "do this for me" I'm just asking for tips. It's not hard to read text correctly. The only Javascript I have currently is the code I have put in. Yes, I want it to show "Hi" first to make sure it will execute properly when I finish the actual code for the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your pointers! I think I figured out words and spaces, so I have an idea on how to go about sentences and average words.